# Integrate payment features in E-Commerce Website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, e-commerce, payment-gateway, payment

I have built a simple e-commerce website using React and JavaScript. Now I want to add payment method when customers buying products. Can you recommend reliable payment gateways that support both card and PayPal payments? Any good documentation that you recommend about integrating payment features?

I just want to add payment features and now I don't know how I start

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.